# how to add value in specified index?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have list of dataSet.

```
List<Model> list = [];
```

...

There is some process to add data to list.

I want pass index to the method. I want to replace data.

I tried these 3 ways, but not replacing..adding another new value.

```
list.insert(widget.configureIndex, model);//1

list[widget.configureIndex] = model;//Error: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

list.replaceRange(widget.configureIndex, widget.configureIndex, [model]);//3
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. In your title, you ask how to replace value in a list, but in your post, you want to *not replace* but adding a new value. Edit your post so that everyone can understand, please?

Comment: please add full code to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you have is that your list does not have a value at the index where you're trying to replace.

```
List<Model> list = [];
int configureIndex = 2;
// None of these work because your list is empty to begin with. 
emptyList.insert(configureIndex, model);
emptyList[configureIndex] = model;
emptyList.replaceRange(configureIndex, configureIndex, [model]);


// Your list must have a value at the index you want to replace

list = [model, model, model]; // list now has value at index 2
if(list.length > configureIndex) { // These will work!
  emptyList.insert(configureIndex, model);
  emptyList[configureIndex] = model;
  emptyList.replaceRange(configureIndex, widget.configureIndex, [model]);
}
```